# dmidecode reports no ram at all - Acer c720 - boots Ubuntu

Tags: ram, chromebook

Machine: Chromebook Acer c720p, Google-Peppy, 32 GB Storage, 4 GB RAM.

I have taken an old Acer c720 Chromebook, removed the write-protect screw, etc., and loaded Sea Bios / Ubuntu 16.04. In order to do the installation, I had to edit the install command via the Grub menu to add something like "mem=1800MB."

Checking free and running memcheck86+ and pretty much any other diagnostic, it shows my memory in the 1.8 GB range. For an example, lshw -c memory shows: 
*-memory description: System memory 
physical id: 1 
size: 1874MiB

Furthermore, dmidecode shows:
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs. 
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

...and that's it. It shows NOTHING about the physical RAM on the machine. Even in the full report, it's like the RAM isn't even there.
So as I've looked for a solution, it seems like the mem=1800MB declaration that I made in order to install the OS in the first place potentially made a partition on the SSD for the memory -- and in the process, the RAM isn't even accessed.

I think that the "solutions" I've seen online are actually missing the fact altogether that the RAM isn't even being recognized. And it's possible that some of the solutions offered -- like what I am looking at in option 1 below -- actually causes the OS to look for the RAM where it SHOULD look instead of going to a manufactured partition that was created in the installation process.

Answers to Questions I frequently Ask Myself: Did the RAM work for the Chrome OS before the install? Yes. How much RAM is there? 4 GB.

So, the questions I am asking:

1) Has anyone faced this? Does finding the "mem=" directive in the boot file and deleting it fix everything (possibly for reason unintended)? 
1a) If so, how does one find and edit this once the OS is installed? It was easier to get to the Grub menu and change the command before Ubuntu was installed.

2) Is there an issue with Ubuntu recognizing the RAM of the Acer 720 machines?

3) Is there something else I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: If your `mem=1800M` kernel parameter is still set, you find it in the file `/etc/default/grub` in the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`. After you remove the parameter (not the whole line!) run `sudo update-grub` to regenerate the real GRUB config files from it and then reboot.

Comment: I've just checked in on Grub and there's no mention of the mem= command, so that initial thought of mine must have been incorrect. When I run dmidecode -t 17 it shows absolutely nothing. free -m shows Mem: 1874 total and Swap: 1985 total. The behavior makes me believe it is entirely a partition on the SSD.

Comment: When I run dmidecode, I notice it says "Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs." Is it possible sysfs somehow has incorrect info stored? Is there a way to view this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to run with no working RAM and only a swap partition, and even if it was possible, it would be horribly slow, even with an SSD. Are you running `dmidecode` correctly as root or with `sudo`?

Comment: sudo dmidecode -t 17 -- and also just the full "sudo dmidecode" command. In researching this the past few days,I've come across a few other people who have had dmidecode show no RAM info although that was never addressed in the answers. Seems odd... and this computer is one that wouldn't install Ubuntu originally sue to insufficient memory, which is why I added the mem=1800 to the boot command (again after reading up on it).